# How to Remove Multiple Labels for Stacked Points? ArcGIS 10.2.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, labeling, point, overlapping-features

I have a point feature class, in certain areas there are stacked points. These stacked points are accurate. However, when I label the points I am getting a label for each point, which is okay for each unique attribute that is being displayed. However, there are some points that have the same attribute information being displayed, where I would only like one label.

Example:

[image]

How can I display one label for all stacked points if their attribute information is the same? So that it would look like:

[image]

Any thougts? I am using a point feature class from ArcSDE 10.2.2.

I cannot alter that data in any way and I am required to used this dataset. Also, I will be publishing it as a dynamic mapping service and documentation has suggested that Maplex Label Engine is not recommend since it slows down performance.

I am looking for a work around taking account into these requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Approach 1: Maplex *Remove Duplicates*

First, make sure you are using the Maplex Label Engine by checking the box in the Labeling toolbar. You can also set the Maplex Label Engine to be the default in *Customize* > *ArcMap Options* > *Data View* tab > *Default Labeling Properties*.

[image: Maplex]

Second, check the `Remove duplicates` box in the *Label Density* tab of the *Placement Properties* of the layer you are labeling. You can also customize the radius in which duplicates are searched.

[image: Remove duplicates]

## Approach 2: Label classes

If you can't use Maplex (as you've noted) or you are labeling coincident points by a field with unique values for each feature, we need to take a different approach. First, add a new integer field called `Label` to your attribute table.

Second, in field calculator, flag duplicate records by running a [special field calculator expression](http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/38700) on your new field. Use the expression `isDuplicate(!Shape!)`, assuming `Shape` is the name of your geometry field, the `PYTHON_9.3` parser, and the following Python code in the optional code block. This will flag the first instance of each geometry with a `0`, duplicates with a `1`, and null or invalid geometry with a `-1`.

```py
uniqueList = []
def isDuplicate(inputShape):
    if inputShape is None or inputShape.pointCount == 0 or inputShape.firstPoint is None:
        return -1
    else:
      hashableShape = (inputShape.firstPoint.X, inputShape.firstPoint.Y)
      if hashableShape in uniqueList:
        return 1
      else:
        uniqueList.append(hashableShape)
        return 0
```

[image: Field calculator duplicate identification]

Then, you can use [label classes](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/map/working-with-text/displaying-labels-using-label-classes-to-label-fea.htm) to only label features that have a `0` in the `Label` fieldvia a SQL query. This should remove duplicate labels.

[image: Label classes]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I forgot to mention that I will be publishing this data as a dynamic mapping service and I have read that using Maplex Label Engine not recommended since it slows down performance. I am trying to find another workaround.

Comment: @arzola I added an alternative/workaround solution that does not use Maplex.

Comment: @dmahr, great second suggestion.  Elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Create new text field, populate it by concatenation of x,y, label. Find duplicates , they are points not to label.

**UPDATED ANSWER with no modification to table:**

```
def FindLabel ( [FID], [LABEL] ):
  fMin=[FID]
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  lr=arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "ends")[0]
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, ('Shape@XY', "LABEL" ),r'"FID"='+str( [FID] )) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
         aKey=row
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lr, ('Shape@XY', "LABEL","FID" )) as cursor:
      for row in cursor:
         comp=row[:2]
         changes=filter(lambda x: x not in aKey, comp)
         if len(changes)==0:
            fMin=min(fMin,row[2])
  if int([FID])==int(fMin): 
     return aKey[1]
  else:
     return ""
```

tested on shapefile.

Before:

[image]

after

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I forgot to mention that I cannot alter the data in any way, and have to use this specific dataset. I have updated my question.

Comment: My sol is a variation of FelixIP's...just in a separate table.  Labeling is of course based on a join...probably slows things a little for the service, but I have something similar that seems to perform fine for a moderate number of records.

Answer (score 1):

Al the sugggestions were great, but this is my quick work around that I just discovered.

1. In Table on Contents, Right Click layer > Properties
2. Labels Tab
3. Placement Properties
4. Change Point Setting to 'Offset label horizontally around the point' = 'Top Center'

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This solution may be clunky but adequate based on your restrictions...requires some scripting, or at any rate, that's how I'd do it.  You can label based on a joined table.  You can set up a dummy table with a cloned unique identifier in the orig table.  Then use a sorted updatecursor on the label values to only populate a dummy field (in the joined dummy table) for the first unique record value.  Easy to do.  That's the key, getting the joined dummy field filled correctly -- leave the dups empty.  Then with the regular label engine you may conditionally label only the records with values populated...for any overlapping points with unique values, there will be a label.  This is a sort of primitive LUT (look up table).