# Features duplicated in multiple, different fields - label expression to avoid duplicate labels

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, feature-class, expression

Using ArcMap 10.4.1. I am trying to label a feature class of roads, there are 5 types: U.S. Highways, State Highways, County, Municipal, and Off Highway. Sometimes a road feature belongs to two classes (EX. Road 44M is both a County, and Municipal Road) There is just one 44M road, but it is listed as both of these types, so when I go to label, it duplicates the label right next to each other.

Removing duplicates doesn't work because that removes the duplicate labels for one type. Is there a way to write my label expression so it won't duplicate the same label across the different types. I want to solve this problem through labeling, not modifying the dataset.

If this doesn't make enough sense please let me know and I will try to clarify further.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/149513/how-to-remove-multiple-labels-for-stacked-points-arcgis-10-2-2